# how to merge records in sql based on time

Tags: sql, vb.net

for my survey software, which contains a lot of MCQ's, wherein a user may navigate back and forth in the survey and select 2/more different options for the same question. each options selected is stored in an SQL database associated with a Question_ID. so in order to analyse and mark the given options for the survey, there may be some cases where there are 2/more options selected for the same question.

I have also included a `Time -time(7)` field in the table. This field stores the time when the option was selected. So how can i go ahead doing ahead.
SO how can i overwrite all the answers to the same question with the option that was chosen the last? Is it feasible and what is the SQL command/s.

Table structure:

```
Question_ID - int (FK) 
Survey_ID - int (FK) 
Time_chosen - time (7) 
Chosen_option - varchar(50)
```

Note: the front - end is VB 2012

So should i include such a code in the front end or the back-end
Thank you

Comment: You will need to provide an example of the schema of your tables so that we can understand how the data is stored before we can help. Also you should supply some sample code that you have tried, whether it works or not.

Comment: Table structure: 

Question_ID - int (FK)

Survey_ID - int (FK)
Time_chosen - time (7)
Chosen_option - varchar(50)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using SQL Server, I would suggest creating a view that contains all of the most recent answers only:

```
CREATE VIEW LatestAnswers
AS
SELECT
    Question_ID,
    Survey_ID,
    Time_Chosen,
    Chosen_Option
FROM
    (SELECT
        Question_ID,
        Survey_ID,
        Time_Chosen,
        Chosen_Option,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Question_ID, Survey_ID ORDER BY Time_Chosen DESC) AnswerOrder
    FROM
        AnswersTable) Answers
    WHERE
        AnswerOrder = 1
```

Comment: thank you! but can I use this suggested solution to be a part wherein i can insert related data into another table??

Comment: The important part here is the ROW_NUMBER() OVER() part. What that does is rank each answer with a number of 1-n, where n is the number of answers. By ordering by Time_Chosen descending that means that the newest answer for each question is assigned 1. You can use that same column select in any query against that table and use it to get the newest answer. Where you put the results is up to you.#